# Import data from excel to sql by nodes

Tags: sql-server, excel, import

```
Hi ,,
I have an Excel file
It has 2 columns ,Province And City
Province column repeats Name for Each city , so it has duplicated values
I want Export this file to MSSQL
in MSSQL ;My table has three columns : Id(AutoGenerate) , Location(Province,City) , ProvinceId

I want import just 1 column from excel
like Below
```

```
province       City
-----------------------
   P1           C1
   P1           C2
   P1           C3
   P1           C4
   P1           C5
   P1           C6
   P1           C7
-------------------------
   P2           C1
   P2           C2
   P2           C3
   P2           C4
   P2           C5
   P2           C6
   P2           C7    

In mssql it Must be :

Id  Location    ProvinceId
----------------------------------------
1      P1               0
2      C1               1
3      C2               1
4      C3               1
5      C4               1
6      C5               1
7      C6               1
8      C7               1
9      P2               0
10     C1               9
11     C2               9
12     C3               9
13     C4               9
14     C5               9
15     C6               9
16         C7               9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do in several steps:

1. Take only province and post them into data base.
2. Extract posted provinces and update new ProvinceId to every city (in excel it is peace of cake)
3. Post all cities

Or you need to write much more smarter sql script to do this at ones in sql.

Comment: Thanks , I need aql scripts .please give me some good refrence

Comment: I used Bulk insert text file http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx if you have permissions. Or you can also try http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx